# Can not link Boost Graph Library for read_graphviz() example

Tags: c++, boost, graphviz, boost-graph

I am trying to do an example with read_graphviz but I can not help the linker to link the read_graphviz function call to the correct version read_graphviz.

At http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/graph/doc/read_graphviz.html there are three template versions of read_graphviz: 
        namespace boost {

```
  template <typename MutableGraph>
  bool read_graphviz(std::istream& in, MutableGraph& graph,
                     dynamic_properties& dp,
                     const std::string& node_id = "node_id");

  template <typename MutableGraph>
  bool read_graphviz(std::string& str, MutableGraph& graph,
                     dynamic_properties& dp,
                     const std::string& node_id = "node_id");

  template <typename InputIterator, typename MutableGraph>
  bool read_graphviz(InputIterator begin, InputIterator end,
                     MutableGraph& graph, dynamic_properties& dp,
                     const std::string& node_id = "node_id");
}
```

I am trying to call the second version of it.
Here is my example code:

```
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map/dynamic_property_map.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>

using namespace boost;

typedef boost::adjacency_list < 
    boost::vecS,
    boost::vecS,
    boost::undirectedS,
    boost::property<boost::vertex_index_t, int>,
    boost::property<boost::edge_index_t, int>> Graph;


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

  Graph dual_g;

  boost::dynamic_properties dp;

  boost::property_map<Graph, boost::vertex_index_t>::type vIndex = get(boost::vertex_index, dual_g);
  dp.property("vertex_id",vIndex);

  boost::property_map<Graph, boost::edge_index_t>::type eIndex = get(boost::edge_index, dual_g);
  dp.property("edge_id", eIndex);

  read_graphviz("dtest.dot", dual_g , dp); //, "node_id");


  return 0;
}
```

I trying to compile using the command:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main -lboost_system
```

The Error:

```
/tmp/cctwokpF.o: In function `bool boost::read_graphviz_new<boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, boost::property<boost::vertex_index_t, int, boost::no_property>, boost::property<boost::edge_index_t, int, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS> >(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, boost::property<boost::vertex_index_t, int, boost::no_property>, boost::property<boost::edge_index_t, int, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>&, boost::dynamic_properties&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost17read_graphviz_newINS_14adjacency_listINS_4vecSES2_NS_11undirectedSENS_8propertyINS_14vertex_index_tEiNS_11no_propertyEEENS4_INS_12edge_index_tEiS6_EES6_NS_5listSEEEEEbRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERT_RNS_18dynamic_propertiesESJ_[_ZN5boost17read_graphviz_newINS_14adjacency_listINS_4vecSES2_NS_11undirectedSENS_8propertyINS_14vertex_index_tEiNS_11no_propertyEEENS4_INS_12edge_index_tEiS6_EES6_NS_5listSEEEEEbRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERT_RNS_18dynamic_propertiesESJ_]+0x80): undefined reference to `boost::detail::graph::read_graphviz_new(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, boost::detail::graph::mutate_graph*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to link the implementation of the functions.

Simplest way is to include it:

```
#include  <libs/graph/src/read_graphviz_new.cpp>
```

In case you like more samples for inspiration: [read_graphviz src](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+read_graphviz+src)

Comment: I tried to include it, but it cannot be found 
main.cpp:14:49: fatal error: libs/graph/src/read_graphviz_new.cpp: No such file or directory
 #include  <libs/graph/src/read_graphviz_new.cpp>
                                                 ^
compilation terminated.

Comment: @Angelos The canonical approach is to link `libboost_grap.a/.so/.dll`. On Win32 this ought to be automatic. On linux, including the file like I said is definitely easiest, but it requires the Boost distribution archive. If you don't have it, use the prebuilt library - wherever you install boost from if you didn't build it yourself.

Comment: thx for your reply. I am using Arch Linux and I had install boost libraries from Arch repository. The linker was needed that flag `-lboost_graph`, I didn't new it, but I found it when you told me about `libboost_grap.a/.so/.dll`. If you add that flag, there is no need for `#include  <libs/graph/src/read_graphviz_new.cpp>`