# Link Boost Graph Library for read_graphviz() in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

When trying to do the boost read_graphviz example at [Read grahviz example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/graph/doc/read_graphviz.html) in Visual Studio on Windows, I get linker errors.

I've build the boost library and referenced it *"\boost_1_72_0"* under C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories. I've linked the libraries *"boost_1_72_0\stage\lib"* under Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories.

However, when compiling I get this:

> LNK2019   unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl boost::detail::graph::read_graphviz_new(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,class boost::detail::graph::mutate_graph *)"

I got it working by referencing the read_graphviz implementation directly *"libs/graph/src/read_graphviz_new.cpp"* as seen in the example below, as suggested here [SO - can-not-link-boost-graph-library-for-read-graphviz-example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37382433/can-not-link-boost-graph-library-for-read-graphviz-example).

Referencing the implementation directly seems like a bad solution. Other parts of the boost graph library can be used fine without referencing the implementation.

How can I use the boost read_graphviz without referencing the implementation directly?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost\graph\graph_traits.hpp>
#include <boost\graph\adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost\graph\dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>
#include <boost\graph\graphviz.hpp>
#include <libs\graph\src\read_graphviz_new.cpp>

using namespace boost;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   typedef property < vertex_name_t, std::string, property < vertex_color_t, float > > vertex_p;
   typedef property < edge_weight_t, double > edge_p;
   typedef property < graph_name_t, std::string > graph_p;
   typedef adjacency_list < vecS, vecS, directedS, vertex_p, edge_p, graph_p > graph_t;

   graph_t graph(0);
   dynamic_properties dp;
   property_map<graph_t, vertex_name_t>::type name = get(vertex_name, graph);
   dp.property("node_id", name);
   ref_property_map<graph_t*, std::string> gname(get_property(graph, graph_name));
   dp.property("name", gname);
   std::istringstream gvgraph("digraph { graph [name=\"graphname\"]  a  c e }");
   bool status = read_graphviz(gvgraph, graph, dp, "node_id");
}
```